# adb can't detect Genymotion device

Tags: virtualbox, android, adb, genymotion

I create an Android device in Genymotion : Custom Phone Android 4.4-API 19, and the device run well.

But when I try '`adb devices`, it is empty below 'List of devices attached'

[image]

'Use custom Android SDK tools' is already set

[image]

the device's Developer Options and USB debugging is enabled.

I have tried

- adb kill-server  adb start-server adb devices

but the adb still can not detect the Genymotion device.

virtualbox as follow

[image]

Runing on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Does anybody have the same problem ? Please help, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55180833/476228) to be helpful for a similar situation. I'm not really sure what the underlying bug is (either in adb or Genymotion), but until it gets fixed this is a suitable workaround. Essentially you're explicitly pointing adb to the device with `adb connect ...`